# VS2013 - Coded UI Tests - how to disable logging

Tags: visual-studio-2013, coded-ui-tests

After migrating my coded ui test from VS2012 to VS2013 I'm facing a debug trace logging problem. What ever the used configuration I still getting debug trace messages !!!
[image: Test Output]

I did add the following configuration :

```
 <system.diagnostics>
<switches>
  <!-- Trace settings for MTR -->
  <!-- Change the value to change the level of tracing you want.
        You must use integral values for "value".  
        0 ==> off,
        1 ==> error,
        2 ==> warn, 
        3 ==> info,
        4 ==> verbose.
        Note that each value is inclusive of the last.
    -->
  <add name="UITestTraceLevel" value="0" />
  <add name="EqtTraceLevel" value="0" />
  <add name="TestManagement" value="0" />
  <add name="TeamBuild" value="0" />
  <add name="TeamFoundationSoapProxy" value="0" />
</switches>
<trace autoflush="true"/>
```

to all the following files :

- project configuration file
- QTAgent.exe.config
- QTAgent_35.exe.config
- QTAgent_40.exe.config
- QTAgent32.exe.config
- QTAgent32_35.exe.config
- QTAgent32_40.exe.config

Did any one have any hint or a workaround to disable this debug trace ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that this is set to NO

```
<appSettings>
<add key="CreateTraceListener" value="no"/>
```

Comment: doesn't help either :(

Comment: Tell me more about the way you run your tests (from VS or MTM..Release or Debug mode...). Are you using the latest VS2013? Any particular plugins

Comment: I'm running the tests from VS 2013 (update 2) on Debug mode. on the same machine i did install "Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Coded UI Test Plugin for Silverlight"

Comment: If I look at your debug trace it does seem that SL (silverlight) is responsible for that trace. The plugin must also have it's own config file just like QTAgent. Also if you run your test in "Release" mode, what happens?

Comment: Thank you. I did post a question to the plugin developer. Waiting for his answer.